# Issue with Java Generics,collection interface and object class

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm trying to create a b-tree class that implements the collection interface shown below. The Issue here is that the add method takes in an object and my node classes setleftNode takes in a Node of a generic type "T". Thus I'm getting method cant be applied to given type error when compiling. :

**B-Tree Class**:

```
public class BST<T> implements Collection<T>{
    private Node<T> _root;
    private Node<T> _current;
    private Random _rnd = new Random();

    public BST(Node<T> root) {
    _root = root;
    }
    public  Node<T> getRoot(){
    return _root;
    }
@Override
public Iterator iterator() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}


@Override
public boolean add(Object e) {
    if (this._root != null){
            if(this._root.getLeftNode() == null){
            this._root.setLeftNode(e);
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

**Node Class:**

```
    public class Node<T>{
    private T _value;
    private Node<T> _left;
    private Node<T> _right;
    public Node (T value){
    _value = value;
    }
    public T getValue(){
    return _value;
    }
    public void setLeftNode(Node<T> node){
    _left= node;
    }
    public void setRightNode(Node<T> rNode){
    _right = rNode;
    }
    public Node getRightNode(){
    return _right;
    }
    public Node getLeftNode(){
    return _left;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but shouldn't it be `public boolean add(<T> element) {`?

Comment: You appear to be trying to add a `Node<T>` as an element of a `Collection<T>`. You probably want `public class BST<T> implements Collection<Node<T>> { @Override public boolean add(Node<T> e) { ...`

Comment: thanks Tome. I think your suggestion will work

Comment: This is not a B-tree, it is a binary tree. They aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `BST<T>` implements `Collection<T>` it should have `add(T e)`. And inside `setLeftNode(new Node<T>(e)))`:

```
@Override
public boolean add(T e) {
    if (this._root != null){
        if(this._root.getLeftNode() == null) {
            this._root.setLeftNode(new Node<T>(e));
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I then get the error that the add method for collection was not overrided.

Comment: it compiles on my machine with java6. what java version do you have?

Comment: I'm using java SE 7. I turned the constructor to this:               public class BST<T> implements Collection<Node<T>>{}. And it seems to work.

Comment: Can you share the method signature of `public boolean add(Object e)` after up-gradation ? As per java doc [collection interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) have a method like `add(T e)`.

Answer (score 0):

you want your BST class to work with the type T, so you should define the add method likewise

```
public boolean add(T e) {
...
}

BST<String> bst = new BST<String>();
bst.add(new String("Hello"))
```